# One zero eigenvalue, how will this affect the phase portrait?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, graphing-functions

I have a Jacobian matrix, and after subbing in the equilibria $0,0$ I get

$$[-1 \ \  0 \\ 0 \ \ \ \ 0]$$.

The eigenvalues are $0$ and $-1$. I believe that because of this there will be a line of fixed points which will be stable. My question is how do I find the eigenvectors and where will the line be?

Comment: What is the matrix? Without knowing it it's difficult to find the eigenvectors.

Comment: The trajectories are indeed straight lines in this case, but as Emilio Novati states, we need the original matrix to find the eigenvectors. Those will give you the direction of the line, but its position depends on the initial conditions.

Comment: The matrix equations are $\dot{x}=x(y-1)$ and $\dot{y}=y^{2}(x-1)$

Answer (score 0):

The eigenvector of $\left[ \matrix{-1 & 0\cr 0 & 0\cr}\right]$ for eigenvalue $0$ is $\pmatrix{0\cr 1\cr}$.

There may or may not be a line (or curve) of equilibrium points.  It depends on more than just the Jacobian at one equilibrium point.  You need to look at the equations: if the system is 
$$ \eqalign{\dot{x} = f(x,y)\cr \dot{y} = g(x,y)\cr}$$
you're looking for solutions of $f(x,y)=0, g(x,y)=0$.